# Array of dictionaries?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary

I'm very new to objective c and i'm having a bit of trouble with my codes. I have an array that contains a list of the countries in the world. Now i want to create out of that array a number of dictionaries according to the alphabet, and then put all of these dictionaries in one array for example:

This is my array of countries:

- "Afghanistan"
- "Albania"
- "Algeria"
- "Angola"
- "Argentina"
- "Bahamas"
- "Cuba"
- "Denmark"

from that array I want to create this:

```
          NSArray


          NSDictionary{
                        headerTitle: "A"
                        rowValue: ("Argentina", "Albania", "Algeria"....etc)
                       }


          NSDictionary {
                        headerTitle: "B"
                        rowValue: ("Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh"....etc)
                       }

                      etc...
```

Now i cant hard code this because the list of countries keep changing since i get my array of countries from a webserver. I would appreciate if you guys could show me how to get this Array of dictionaries(alphabetically) from my array of countries. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want an array of dictionaries, each with one entry? Why wouldn't you use either a dictionary with 26 entries or an array that holds 26 other arrays?

Comment: because I need this structure array so I could use it on my UItableview. For the method (tableview numberOfRowsInSection) I was going to iput this code [[[content objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] count] ;

Comment: also for the cell.textlabel.text = [[[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"]
                           objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: I went ahead and included a data source implementation you can use. I think this code is probably pretty minimal but still flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@implementation NSArray (CountryNamesArray)

+(NSArray*)sectionsArrayFromCountryNames:(NSArray*)countryNames
{
        NSMutableDictionary * countriesDict = [ NSMutableDictionary dictionary ] ;

        for( NSString * countryName in countryNames )
        {
            NSString * firstLetter = [ [ countryName substringToIndex:1 ] uppercaseString ] ;
            NSDictionary * countryDict = countriesDict[ firstLetter ] ;
            if ( ! countryDict ) { countryDict = @{ @"headerTitle" : firstLetter, @"rowValues" : [ NSMutableArray array ] }; } ;

            [ countryDict[@"rowValues"] addObject:countryName ] ;
        }

        return [ countriesDict allValues ] ;
}

@end
```

This is a category on NSArray that does what you want.

Use like this

```
NSArray * countriesArray = [ NSArray sectionsArrayFromCountryNames:<#countryNames#> ];
```

But, I think a better way might be to have a sorted array of section names, and the section names are keys into a dictionary whose values are the rows for each section. Like this:

```
// protocol all your cells will support
@protocol TableViewCell
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) id value ;  // value cell should display in table
+(NSString*)reuseIdentifier ;
+(instancetype)cell ;
@end

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell<TableViewCell>
@end

@implementation TableViewCell

@synthesize value = _value ;

-(void)setValue:(id)value
{
    _value = value ;
    self.textLabel.text = value ;
}

+(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
{
    return NSStringFromClass( self ) ;
}

+(instancetype)cell
{
    return [[ [ self class ] alloc ] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[ self reuseIdentifier ] ] ;
}

@end

@interface TableViewDataSource ()
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSArray * cityNames ;
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSArray * sectionTitles ;
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) NSMutableDictionary * sectionsDictionary ;
@end

@implementation TableViewDataSource

-(void)setCityNames:(NSArray*)names
{
    NSMutableSet * sectionTitles = [ NSMutableSet set ] ;
    NSMutableDictionary * newSectionsDict = [ NSMutableDictionary dictionary ] ;

    for( NSString * cityName in names )
    {
        NSString * sectionTitle = [[ cityName substringToIndex:1 ] uppercaseString ] ;
        [ sectionTitles addObject:sectionTitle ] ;
        NSMutableArray * sectionRows = newSectionsDict[ sectionTitle ] ;
        if ( !sectionRows )
        {
            sectionRows = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:cityName ] ;
            newSectionsDict[ sectionTitle ] = sectionRows ;
        }
        else
        {
            [ sectionRows addObject:cityName ] ;
        }
    }

    self.sectionTitles = [[ sectionTitles allObjects ] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector( compare: ) ] ;
    self.sectionsDictionary = newSectionsDict ;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.sectionTitles.count ;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [ self.sectionsDictionary[ self.sectionTitles[ section ] ] count ] ;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Class<TableViewCell> cellClass = [ TableViewCell class ] ;  // 'cellClass' could change based on type of value to be displayed
    TableViewCell * cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[ cellClass reuseIdentifier ] ] ;
    if ( !cell )
    {
        cell = [ cellClass cell ] ;
    }
    cell.value = self.sectionsDictionary[ self.sectionTitles[ indexPath.section ] ][ indexPath.row ] ;
    return cell ;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.sectionTitles[ section ] ;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.sectionTitles ;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return index ;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a section array:

```
NSArray* sectionArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [@"A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|#" componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];
```

Take the first letter, use checks before using substring:

```
NSString *firstLetter = [strValue substringToIndex:1];
```

Add it the the proper section array, so at the end you should have 27 keys Dict with arrays as object. Hope this helps!

Please note that there is no direct method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly put together this pseudocode, but this uses a dictionary as opposed to an array as you requested. Hope it helps.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *countryFirstLetters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *countryName in countries)
    {
        NSString *firstLetter = [[countryName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        NSMutableDictionary *firstLetterDict = countryFirstLetters[firstLetter];
        if (!firstLetterDict)
        {
            firstLetterDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        }
        firstLetterDict[@"headerTitle"] = firstLetter;

        NSMutableString *rowValueString = firstLetterDict[@"rowValue"];
        if (!rowValueString)
        {
            rowValueString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:countryName];
        }
        else
        {
            [rowValueString appendFormat:@", %@", countryName];
        }
        firstLetterDict[@"rowValue"] = rowValueString;

        countryFirstLetters[firstLetter] = firstLetterDict;
    }
```